# Replace values of a matrix with a new value

Tags: r

I have a numeric data matrix that looks like below:
(Matrix)

```
            Sample1     Sample2       Sample3         Sample4

BD.1809   0.4275       -1.034         0.857757         -1.43362
BD.911    0.4455       -1.456         -0.472828        -0.643979
BP.12     0.03642      -0.9054        1.03334          -0.02428
BS.114    -0.3262      4.677          -0.92514         -0.2435
BS.130    -0.2335      -0.8661        -1.21435         -0.9759
BS.376    0.1937       -1.043         -0.320004        -0.691325
```

I have calculated the mean with the following code  `Mean<-mean(Matrix)`

How would I replace each value in the matrix with the Mean?

can any one give me tips on how to do this? The row and column names are unknown as are the values themselves and the size of the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m <- matrix(1:10,nrow=2)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10

> mean(m)
[1] 5.5
> m[,] <- mean(m)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  5.5  5.5  5.5  5.5  5.5
[2,]  5.5  5.5  5.5  5.5  5.5
```